# sql server enumerate current session variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to enumerate the currently-defined session variables?  I've been looking for the equivalent of

```
select * from sys.tables
```

for session variables, but I can't find a sys view that contains that information.  I'm wondering if it's possible to spin through them and print them to the response window.  I've got about 35+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this DMV.  It has all the current session variables plus their values.  They are in columnar format, btw.  This will return the info on your current connection:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id = @@SPID
```

Also, here is the Books online article to interpret the columns (e.g. ansi_defaults column = ANSI_DEFAULTS setting for the session):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: While it's not quite what I was looking for, that's some good information, and your answer wasn't "no you can't".  So I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

No its not possible to retrieve that information from SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean Session vars as in ASP.net, then NO.

Comment: I am not referring to asp.net.  I am referring to SQL.